# jQuery.js not loading after enabling custom module

Tags: javascript

I have written my custom module for Drupal 7. In my `page_change.module` file I have only:

```
<?php
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'page_change') . '/page_change.js');
?>
```

In my `page_change.js` file I have only:

```
Drupal.behaviors.page_change = {
    attach: function (context) {
        console.log("text");
    }
};
```

As soon as I enable my module, Drupal doesn't load `jquery.js`. It does not even appear in html source in `<head>` section. When I disable my module, or delete the only line from `page_change.module` file everything works fine.

I have also tried to load my javascript file by adding

```
scripts[] = page_change.js
```

In my `page_change.info` file (and leaving `page_change.module` with only `<?php ?>`) but it doesn't seem to work either.

Why does that happen? What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

edit: I have even tried to add inline javascript by adding

```
drupal_add_js('console.log("text");', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
```

and it writes `text` to console, but `jquery.js` is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, somehow I forced it to work, but I still have no idea why it hadn't work before.

I have changed my `page_change.module` contents to:

```
<?php
function page_change_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $file = drupal_get_path('module', 'page_change').'/page_change.js';
    $options = array(
      'weight' => 1000,
      'scope' => 'footer'
    );
    drupal_add_js($file, $options);
}
?>
```

then I disabled and enabled my module and miraculously it works.

If you have any idea why I had these problems, please post your answer.

Comment: I had this issue and by changing the hook to hook_init() worked. If you don't mind having this fire right away instead of when preprocess_page fires, I have a feeling it would work. It did for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your custom JS should be wrapped in:

```
(function($) {
  // custom Drupal behaviors here
})(jQuery);
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: I do not use jQuery in my javascript. I've tried this, it doesn't help. Problem is that Drupal does not load jQuery when I add any javascript, not the javascript itself. Javascript works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, this issue is actually with what Drupal outputs in the source. jQuery.js is not output in this case.